# Why doesn't duplicate IDs throw an error?

Tags: html, css, dom, html-parsing

I did a quick search and couldn't find anything useful for this question.  Is there a reason that browsers don't throw a warning or error to the console if there are duplicate IDs on DOM elements?  Seems like browsers should realize there are duplicates when they parse your dom structure.

Comment: The W3Validator definitely throws out an error.

Comment: It is probably to accomodate the older markup and browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because browser HTML parsers don't perform any debugging functionality whatsoever. They just try to cope with whatever they get as best they can.

End users don't need to know if there is a non-fatal error, and there aren't any fatal errors in HTML. (Throwing a fatal error on a non-well-formed XHTML document was such a popular feature that most (all?) modern browsers will silently switch to an HTML parser instead of displaying the error to the end user).

Developers should use validation tools to QA their work.

Comment: I would rather say that end users just would not benefit much from error and warning messages, partly because errors are so common that distinguishing serious issues from common sloppyness would be very difficult. And browsers do use XML parsing for XHTML documents – when served with an XHTML content type.

Comment: Browsers do throw warnings to the console for css rules that are broken or content type mismatches, both of which don't affect the end user

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. It doesn't have an API which could be used to throw errors.

Comment: HTML parsers are written in programming languages and do have APIs which could be used to throw errors.